# How to convert time format to a number format (Google Sheets/Data Studio)

Tags: google-sheets, number-formatting, looker-studio

I want to convert the numbers in ColA to normal numbers, like the ones I have in ColB. The one in ColA currently are in this format: 00:56:00.000. I initially started out with a time length, that I then converted to seconds (what's currently in ColA). I need to convert them back into a single number to import into Data Studio so it can read it as time. If I try to change the formatting to a number it comes up as a decimal, how can I change the format to a number? Or can I do it in Data Studio?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xaAfc6hcFJJ1JsPfrx9Ly3usfljuzELT80UsgSxcNM8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on col `B3` on Google Sheets while `A3:A` is converted into number format (in decimals):

```
=Arrayformula((A3:A*3600)*24)
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Explanation:**

This is just an observation, but it seems that Google Data Studio strictly follows the formatting of the cell values. If you want to read the seconds as integers, a few arithmetic operations was performed to convert the number formatting of duration as such presented above.

**Apps Script (use this if removing helper column B):**

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = ss.getRange('A3:A').getValues();

  Logger.log(data);

  var second = 3600;
  var hour = 24;
  var output = data.map(x => [x[0] * second * hour]);
  ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(3, 1, output.length, output[0].length).setValues(output);
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change format to seconds only.